# submit form in ajax php mvc data not saved

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm trying to submit a form with Ajax.

In my form, I have the followin submit button

```
<?php echo CHtml::Button('SUBMITAjax',array('onclick'=>'send();')); ?>
```

the send function is a jquery script

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("post/Ajax"); ?>',
   data:data,
success:function(data){
                alert("Data Saved"); 
              },
   error: function(data) { // if error occured
         alert("Error occured.please try again");
         alert(data);
    },

  dataType:'html'
  });
```

the Ajax php function contains this code

```
$model=new Comment;

if(isset($_POST['CommentForm']))
        {


            $model->attributes=$_POST['CommentForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
               // form inputs are valid, do something here
               $model->save();
               return;



            }
        }
```

Everything works fine  but the data is not saved.

What is wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `everything works fine`?

Comment: did you check in firebug any error? and is data posted correctly. try using print_r() in php and see what is response? 
see there are not any rules or access permissions not voilated.

Comment: The success message is displayed

Comment: @Learner Student,   I'll check tonight (I'm not at home now) and post the response.

Comment: Please put try catch block for model save and check what error is coming

Comment: try to use if(!$model->save(false)) die('ko');

Comment: @Learner Student   - the response is empty

Comment: Please confirm that data is posted to php is ok. Chk in firbug net tab. Params

Answer (score 0):

why do not you simply create a form like this and submit it using ajax

```
<?php
     echo CHtml::beginForm();
     echo CHtml::textField('name');

     echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('submit form', Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("post/Ajax"),array(
         'success'=>new CJavaScriptExpression('function(data)
             {
alert(data);             
}
             ')
     ));
     echo CHtml::endForm();
    ?>
```

Learn about ajaxUbmitButton [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton)